# kea-dhcp-server logs vs isc-dhcp-server logs

Tags: dhcp, log, dhcpd

So switching from isc to kea dhcp server I can't seem to find "device name" (in this example, Chromecast-Ultra) in the log anymore.

I.e. with the isc dhcp server I would get:

> Jun  2 23:45:15 gallifrey dhcpd[3303]: DHCPACK on 10.20.31.183 to f4:f5:d8:a9:58:c6 **(Chromecast-Ultra)** via eno1

With the new kea dhcp server I get:

> 2024-02-06 09:18:48.682 INFO  [kea-dhcp4.leases/28556.139763533520512] DHCP4_LEASE_ALLOC [hwtype=1 f4:f5:d8:a9:58:c6], cid=[no info], tid=0x47ebfe1b: lease 10.20.31.183 has been allocated for 3600 seconds

Is there a way to make kea dhcp server log this "device name" as well, like the old dhcp server did?

Comment: Have you tried the ["kea-dhcp4.ddns" logging parameter](https://docs.netgate.com/tnsr/en/latest/dhcp/logging.html)?

Comment: hello @DanielT. I tried adding a couple. now I have 
> "kea-dhcp4"
> "kea-dhcp4.dhcpsrv"
> "kea-dhcp4.ddns"
> "kea-dhcp4.hosts" 
> "kea-dhcp4.hooks"
> "kea-dhcp4.leases"
None of which seem to produce the "device names"